How are these bimetallic brake rotors made?
Shimano's high-end brake rotors for bicycles feature "Ice-Tech" construction. This consists of a 3-layer sandwich of steel (for the braking surfaces), aluminum, and then steel again. Compared with a conventional all-steel rotor, this is claimed to offer better heat conduction out of the braking surfaces and reduce the rotor's weight. In addition, the aluminum extends beyond the steel and the resulting cooling fins supposedly improve radiative heat rejection.
 
My question is, how exactly might this sandwich be made? What manufacturing process(es) are used to permanently attach the steel to the aluminum like that? I'd imagine it's not an adhesive as that would A: act as a thermal barrier and decrease heat transfer, and B: decompose and release under intense heat.

How are the cooking pans with multiple metals made? check out types of welding.

explosive welding is the norm here - https://triclad.com/aluminium-steel-welding/

@PhilSweet Extremely cool. Thanks!

Aluminum cannot be welded onto steel by ordinary welding processes, but a sheet of steel can be smashed into adhesion with a sheet of aluminum by the use of explosives. the link Phil Sweet posted shows how.

Phil Sweet could delete his comment
